# Huge result PDF from iText using PdfSmartCopy

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have (in most cases) 2 PDF files, 1 main PDF containing around 30000 pages, and another one containing 1 Page which i want to insert after every X amount of pages to the main one (depending on my seperate index file), while also adding barcodes to each page.

The problem i have is that the result PDF becomes VERY large (10GB+), while the in-files are 350Mb and the small one i want to insert <50kb.

Whats a good way to optimize the size of the PDF Im creating?

Heres the relevant parts of the code handling the PDF merge.

```
PdfImportedPage page;
PdfSmartCopy outPdf;
PdfSmartCopy.PageStamp stamp;
PdfReader pdfReader, pdfInsertReader;

...

outDoc = new Document();
outPdf = new PdfSmartCopy(outDoc, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
pdfToolset = new PDFToolset();
outDoc.open();

...

//loop over pages in my index-file
for (IndexPage index_page : item.pages) {
    if (indexpage.insertPage){
        currentDoc = indexpage.source_file;
        outPdf.freeReader(pdfReader);
        outPdf.flush();
        if (!currentDoc.equals(insertDoc)) {
            insertDoc = currentDoc;
            pdfInsertReader = new PdfReader(currentDoc);
        }
    } else if (!currentDoc.equals(indexpage.source_file)) {
        currentDoc = indexpage.source_file;
        outPdf.freeReader(pdfInsertReader);
        outPdf.flush();
        if (!mainDoc.equals(currentDoc)){
            mainDoc = currentDoc;
            pdfReader = new PdfReader(mainDoc);
        }
    }

    if (indexpage.insertPage)
        page = outPdf.getImportedPage(pdfInsertReader, indexpage.source_page);
    else
        page = outPdf.getImportedPage(pdfReader, indexpage.source_page);

    if (!duplex || (duplex && indexpage.nr % 2 == 1)) {
        stamp = outPdf.createPageStamp(page);
        stamp = pdfToolset.applyBarcode(stamp, indexpage.omr, indexpage.nr);
        stamp.alterContents();
    }
    outPdf.addPage(page);
}

...
```

Comment: I'm not sure if using `freeReader()` is wise in this case. Maybe it's because I don't understand what you're doing, but something in the code looks odd: you have one `mainDoc`, yet you have many different `PdfReader` objects reading the same document? Also: `PdfSmartCopy` can detect identical resources, but if you'll end up with a huge document if each document uses different subsets of the same (or a different) font.

Comment: Its possible that Im using `freeReader()` unwisely. The PDF page I'm inserting every couple pages in this case is the exact same one. Sometimes its 2-3 different pages which are used which maybe is why the code looks weird, I'm keeping the main document in one `PdfReader` the whole time while switching around the small ones in the `pdfInsertReader`. But the resources should be identical each time `pdfInsertReader` is used, while `pdfReader` keeps writing the main file, so the result PDF should be around the same size as the main file. Feels like I'm doing something wrong or missing something.

Comment: Maybe you should add comment to your code so that a second pair of eyes knows where to look. For instance: how many times is this line used: `pdfReader = new PdfReader(mainDoc);`? If more than once, you have found the cause of your problem.

Comment: I found the cause. Every time i call `page = outPdf.getImportedPage(pdfInsertReader, indexpage.source_page);` i get the page that I've already used previously and added a barcode to, so it adds another barcode on top of the old one each time i try to get a "fresh" page from the PDF im inserting (in the end there were thousands of barcodes on top of eachother). Now i just need to find out how to get an original page back instead of the ones i have already modified, since the barcodes differ just a little on each page.